# starting with system & getting webcard serial

Tags: java

Can I write in java program without using native funcs which could set my application to be run with system and Could I check MAC address of my webcard ?

Comment: What is a "webcard"---do you mean any network interface card/controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You don't need the MAC address](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5363319)